# Visual Studio Experimental Instance loading too slow?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, devexpress, dsl, vsix, dsl-tools

I am working on an new visual studio extension and when testing I'm using a vsix project to run the experimental instance, however this takes about 5 minutes just to boot up. I have resharper and devexpress installed on my development instance of VS, I notice that these dlls are loaded when my experimental instance loads up even though I'm not using these dev tools in my extension. I have tried removing the add-in for devexpress from the Toolbox Items on my instance but they are still loaded. Devexpress takes some time to load are because of the many dll's this suite contains. I cannot remove it as I have other projects I am maintaining using Devexpress. Is there anywhere of improving performance and using the instance with no extra add-in's, please advise?

Comment: Are you using any WPF controls and data binding? I had a similiar performance issue with one of my extensions; I noticed that binding errors where logged to Visual Studio´s output window. I disabled logging of binding errors which improved execution time during debugging...

Comment: I am using DSL Tools, but the fact that I have DevExpress Suite, it loads its dll's each time and it take a while.